# Including a script in a jslink file

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, jslink, ctx

I'm building a simple app on a SP2013 online intranet that uses the Google Books API to pull in GB content (title, author, image etc). 
The goal is to modify a SP list view to populate the book isbn using a jslink file, so the correct book gets rendered. My custom item line looks like this but doesn't work:

```
var ret = "<script>var googleAPI = 'https://www.igoogleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + ctx.CurrentItem.Book_x0020_id + "';></script>";
return ret;
```

Is it even possible to include a script variable declaration within a jslink file?
Another option would be to use a calculated field instead, but SP encodes some of the html causing the script to break.

Answer (score 0):

This article is probably what you're looking for. It suggests to create 2 ‘single line of text’ columns with JavaScript and 1 calculated column to put everything together.

[Using JavaScript URL in Calculated Columns](https://sharepoint2020.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/using-javascript-url-in-calculated-columns/)

Comment: Also, that article seems to be addressing syntax issues with inline scripts (quotation marks). This is really about getting a variable to function. Everything needed shows up correctly using either method when I inspect the output but nothing gets rendered. Any other thoughts on how this might be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's not possible. You can include multiple files within JSLInk by using | between the JSLink property in Web Part settings, e.g., `~site/myscript.js|~site/myotherscript.js`, and `myscript.js` would be usable in `myotherscript.js`. It doesn't, however support any variables, so it will not work in you case.

Could you make AJAX call to that Google API from within your main JSLink file?

Comment: That's a good idea but I'm not sure how I would do that within jslink.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out pulling the calculated column in using a **content query web part** works. I added the field ref name in the description box of a cqwp and - bingo.